# localised.string in a language that is not available in settings

Tags: ios, translation

I am creating an app and I have some translations.
The app is programmed to detect the ios language and most of the languages are in the settings, except Slovenian.
Is there any other way to do that.
Perhaps read region format?
Or, how to add a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the OS itself my not support the language (`iPhone Language` setting) you can still use the below option in Settings to `Add Language…` to add the language to your preferred list of languages. Then if an app supports that language it still will even if the OS does not (ie. The OS's strings aren't translated).